# Use Managed metadata with the Content Query Web Part?

Tags: managed-metadata, content-query-web-part, office-365

I'm trying out the Content Query Web Part in Office 365. However, I want to use Managed metadata as a criterion to filter on, but I don't see any of the Managed metadata columns I have created in subsites from the top site where I'm creating a Content Query Web Part... Is there any way for such Managed metadata columns to be available here? All I'm seeing is standard columns, but this post seems to suggest that you should have your custom metadata available:

c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/

And I would assume that means custom columns from sub sites, since creating a new metadata column in the top site wouldn't have any effect on search results...

UPDATE: See this question for an example of the site structure:

[Best practice organization of sites on Sharepoint Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61777/best-practice-organization-of-sites-on-sharepoint-online)

I want to be able to filter on a Managed metadata column that is available in the sub sites, but use it to filter in the top site Content Query Web Part to get an aggregated view of certain documents from the sub sites, based on such a Managed metadata column.

I have already created several Managed metadata columns in the sub sites before, but I cannot see them available in the configuration for the Content Query Web Part, I only see default columns there.

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that you have already configured Managed Metadata service properly and its running and also that you have added Taxonomy Term Store where the needed terms and term categories have added.

If you are done with this basic configuration then within SharePoint Lists and Libraries, this Taxonomy Term Store can be used by creating a column of type 'Managed Metadata'.  You can then choose the Term Set that you intend to use within the list or library.

If this has been done then it should work, Let me know if something mentioned above configuration missing Or it still do not work.

Comment: Yes, I have created such columns in the sub sites, and they work fine within that context, to filter views of Document Libraries. But what I want now is to be able to filter on them in the Content Query Web Part from the top site. See my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting from a specific library in the CQWP.