# Use custom columns with Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, content-query-web-part, office-365

I'm trying to use custom metadata columns with the Content Query Web Part. I finally figured out that I apparently needed to export the .webpart xml file, edit it and then import it as a new web part.

So I made the following changes:

```
<property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" >MinKategori</property>
```

and

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" >MinKategori</property>
```

According to this tip in Answer 4 here: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/filter-content-query-web-part-custom-189739.aspx

This doesn't work for some reason though. I do get the column available, but it says I haven't filled in a value, which I actually have as this image shows, but still I only get the error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it may be because it's managed metadata.

Comment: Ok, but if that's the problem it would sort of defeat the purpose, since managed metadata is what we mostly use in document libraries. Also, I have been under the impression that the CQWP should work with managed metadata columns as well...

Comment: Does the managed metadata column allow multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

See if this link helps you:

http://www.theroks.com/related-items-with-a-content-query-webpart/

> We export the webpart. In the xml there are two elements that we must
>   see. These are the properties; FilterOperator1 and
>   FilterDisplayValue1. FilterDisplayValue1 has the right and expected
>   value. However the FilterOperator1 has the value Eq. This will not do
>   it. When multiple terms are coupled to a FAQ it will never appear in
>   this result.

```
<property name="FilterOperator1"
  type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
 Eq
</property>

<property name="FilterDisplayValue1" type="string">
 [PageFieldValue: Insurrance]
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the constraint "equals" instead of contains.  I am pretty sure you cannot use the contains constraint with term sets but they still work fine if there are multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Site Column of type Managed Metadata and set it to allow multiple values. Associate this site column to a custom Site Content Type.  Add the site content type to your document library/list

In your CQWP : 
- point the query source to show items from the your document library/list you added site content type into.
- Set the content type to site content type you created.
- Under additional filters, set to show items when  "contains all of"  .

Answer (score 0):

### Error message

This error

> You must specify a value for filters on managed metadata fields

occurs when filter value could not be specified for [taxonomy field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.aspx) (TaxonomyFieldType or TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti types) in [Content Query web part editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerytoolpart.aspx).

### Taxonomy fields based filtering in CQWP

By default CQWP support Managed metadata fields, including the single & multi-value varieties  for filtering, see for example [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/14/what-s-new-with-the-content-query-web-part.aspx) article for details.

### Limitation for usage taxonomy fields (multiple values) for filtering  in CQWP

In case of usage multi value taxonomy fields for filtering, it could be specified in web part editor when target list is selected only (see Source property in screenshot below)

For another sources (*Show items from all sites in this site collection* or *Show items from the following site and all subsites*) filtering based on multiple values taxonomy fields could be specified explicitly using properties (filter operator, filter type and filter value). See solution section below for details.

[image]

### Solution

In your case in order to filter by taxonomy field there is no need to provide [AdditionalFilterFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.additionalfilterfields.aspx) and [CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields.aspx) properties.

The following properties should be specified for filtering based on multiple taxonomy field:

[FilterOperator1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filteroperator1.aspx)

Specify [filter operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filterfieldqueryoperator)

```
<property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">ContainsAny</property>
```

[FilterType1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filtertype1.aspx)

To specify multiple taxonomy field:

```
<property name="FilterType1" type="string">TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti</property>
```

[FilterValue1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filtervalue1.aspx)

Specify taxonomy field internal name:

```
<property name="FilterField1" type="string">NewsLocation</property>
```